# Dock Image to the right of StackPanel WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created the following UserControl to display video:

```
<UserControl x:Class="InstallerToolkit.UserControls.UserControlVideoPlayer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="464" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"> 
<Grid Background="Black">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black" >
        <MediaElement Name="MediaElement"  MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" MouseEnter="MediaElement_MouseEnter" />
        <StackPanel Background="Gray">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Gray">
                <Image Name="ImagePlay" Source="/Images/play.png" MouseDown="OnMouseDownPlayMedia"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="25"/>
                <Slider x:Name="timelineSlider"  Thumb.DragStarted="DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="DragCompleted" Margin="5" ValueChanged="SeekToMediaPosition"  Width="70"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblProgressStatus" Margin="5"><Run Text="00:00"/></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblSepatator" Margin="5"><Run Text="/"/></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblTotalLength" Margin="5"><Run Text="00:00"/></TextBlock>
                <Image Name="ImageFullScreen" Source="/images/fullscreen.png"  MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseEnter="ImageFullScreen_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="ImageFullScreen_MouseLeave" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="25" Width="25"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel> 
</Grid>
```

This looks like this:
[image]

I want to position the 'fullscreen' icon way over to the right like this (I mocked this up in Paint):

[image]

I want the fullscreen icon to stay docked to the right and for the controls(Play, slider etc) to always be in the center.

How do I do this??

Comment: Have you tried to substitute the inner StackPanel for a Grid? StackPanel is not very good to dock things on the edge of controls. And a Grid can simulate the effect of a StackPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version of my answer I suggested that you can used a `DockPanel` but then I realized that you probably want the controls to be centered with respect to the `MediaElement` without being affected by the size of the close button `Image`.

You can use a grid and place the controls as well as the close button in the same cell but with different alignment:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <MediaElement/>
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      ... player controls ...
  </StackPanel>
  <Image Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="/images/fullscreen.png" Height="25" Width="25"/>
</Grid>
```

The `StackPanel` is centered while the `Image` is right aligned in the bottom `Grid` row.

Comment: Thanks so much thats perfect, yes I have been trying everything lol

Comment: One more question, with your solution, how do I get the MedaiElement to stretch to fill the whole of its surroundings? For example if I place the UserCOntrol onto a Page and resize it I want the controls to be docked at them bottom and the VideoPLayer to fill the rest of the size?

Comment: I added Stretch="Fill" to the MediaElement and that did the trick :)

Comment: @HarryBoy: The default `Width` and `Height` of a `MediaElement` is `Auto` and the default `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` is `Stretch` so if you place it in a `Grid` cell as I have done it should stretch to fill out this cell as it is resized. If on the other hand you place it inside a `StackPanel` (as you did in your question) the `StackPanel` will "suck up the stretch" resulting in the `MediaElement` not resizing when the container resizes. So get rid of the `StackPanel` and use a `Grid` instead.